# Keeping a class over a java program is this a good way?

Tags: java, jgit

I am making something with JGit

The situation is like this.

The user will open a git repository and use it in various ways.

In the program this repository has information in Repository class and the various functions will access to this repository by calling it. this repository is build by a builder at first like this.

```
FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
        Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(new File(repodir))
            .readEnvironment() // scan environment GIT_* variables
            .findGitDir() // scan up the file system tree
            .build();
```

While making the program I thought I should keep this repository opened and usable through the program. and I have an idea to make a class like this to keep the current opened repository

```
public class CurrentRepo{

    private static Repository repository;

    public static Repository getRepository(){
        return this.repository;
    }

    public static void setRepository(Repository repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }
}
```

After this i will call the

```
CurrentRepo.getRepository()
```

to get information of the repository which is opened.

Would this cause a problem? Is this a bad way?

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Why is `CurrentRepo` declared `static`? Is it an inner class?

Comment: @DavidConrad oh it is not i think it doesn't needs to be declared static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I would say that using a static field to store such an information is okay. However, as you said

> I should keep this repository opened and usable through the program

the gernal question is: is it possible that you are running more than one instances of your program running in the same JVM having different repositories being opened? If this is the case, you should avoid using a static field (aka. called global variable) to store this information. Try to identify a class in your program that can store your information as part of the program's state which lives as long as the program and not as long as the JVM. You can still use a class like `CurrentRepo` that comprises all the information on the currently opened repository, but you should not store this information in static fields.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I see your point. I think making CurrentRepo a singleton kind will be good. is this will be okay?